# Don't understand the *derivation* of geometrically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I don't understand the derivation of geometrically distributed random
variables as done [here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/bernoulli/Geometric.html) (only the first $10$ lines - everything until exercise $2$ -  are relevant for me).

Please bare with me, that I probably need a very formal and thorough explication, since I looked already at different website and books, which used explanations in a similar manner to the link I provided and I didn't understood any of them! (I have my "own" derivation, which makes sense to me, which can be found below)

In the course I took, they weren't rigorously defined, so I more or
less tried to figure out what the professor did and it seems to me
that what is written below is how we derived them. But the derivation
in the link is different! And the central problem seems to be, that
in the link there is a mathematical connection between the random
variables $X_{k}:\left\{ s,f\right\} \rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ \omega\mapsto\omega$
(where our Bernoulli trail sample space is modeled by $\Omega:\left\{ s,f\right\} $,
for " success'' and " failure'' and the whole experiment
is $\Omega^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$), since there they
somehow used that the $X_{k}$ are independent -- which doesn't make
sense at all to me: If $s$ has probability $1>p>0$, then the sets
$\left\{ X_{1}=s\right\} $ and $\left\{ X_{2}=s\right\} $ aren't
independent, because 
$$
P\left(\left\{ X_{1}=s\right\} \cap\left\{ X_{2}=s\right\} \right)=P\left\{ s\right\} =p\neq p^{2}=P\left(\left\{ X_{1}=s\right\} \right)P\left(\left\{ X_{2}=s\right\} \right).
$$

Opposed to that, in my derivation there isn't a mathematical link
between the random variable that has the geometric distribution and
the $X_{k}$.

---

**My derivation:** Consider sequence of Bernoulli trials of finite length $n$ (where
the space for each experiment is for example $\Omega:\left\{ s,f\right\} $).
If $p$ is the probability to get success, $p(1-p)^{k-1}$ is the
probability of having the first success in the $k$th trial, where
$n\geqslant k\left(\geqslant0\right)$. Now we want to know what the
probability is to have first success in the $k$th trial, where we
don't have an upper bound $n$.

Since we don't have a way to define on the space of all infinite sequences,
i.e. $\left(\omega_{1},\omega_{2},\ldots\right)$ mit $\omega_{i}\in\Omega$
a suitable probability distribution starting from our $\Omega$ (at
least I don't know how to do it and using advanced measure theoretic
machinery doesn't count, since I'm interested in hoe the geometric
distribution is defined in " undergraduate'' setting). But we
do know that $p(1-p)^{k-1}$ is independent of $n$, so we *define*
a new $\hat{\Omega}:=\mathbb{N}$ und $\hat{p}\left(k\right):=p\left(1-p\right)^{k}$
we models the fact that we have first success in the $k$th trial.
*Then* we can define $X:\hat{\Omega}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ x\mapsto x$
as the random variable whose distribution is which tells us, when
we get the first succes - but mathematically there is no connection
between this random variable, and the random variables $X_{k}:\left\{ s,f\right\} ^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ \left(\omega_{1},\omega_{2},\ldots,\omega_{n}\right)\mapsto\omega_{k}$
or the random variables $X_{k}:\left\{ s,f\right\} \rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ \omega\mapsto\omega$.

Comment: Why do you think that $P\left(\left\{ X_{1}=s\right\} \cap\left\{ X_{2}=s\right\} \right)=P\left\{ s\right\} =p$? This is like saying that if you toss a fair coin twice, the probability of getting heads twice is $\frac12$, which is clearly false.

Comment: I'm working just formally here, and formally I have $$ P\left(\left\{ X_{1}=s\right\} \cap\left\{ X_{2}=s\right\} \right)= P( \{ s\}\cap \{ s\}) =P\left\{ s\right\}=p. $$ At which "$=$" have I made the error ?

Comment: The first is wrong. In order to talk about $X_1$ and $X_2$, you must consider (at least) $\Omega^2$: you’re looking at $$P\left(\big(\{s\}\times\Omega\big)\cap\big(\Omega\times\{s\}\big)\right)\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah, I seem to get more to the heart of my problem: But why are then the $X_k$ defined as $X_k:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and not $X_k:\Omega^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (by taking the projection and then applying the "previous" $X_k:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) ? Or is it a notation/convention to define $$P(\{X_1=s\}\cap \{X_2 =s\}):=P((\{s\} \times \Omega)\times (\Omega \times \{s\})) ?$$  Since I always understood generally $P(\{Y=s\) \cap \{Z =s\})$ to mean$P(Y^{-1}(s) \cap Z^{-1}(s) )$, such that we don't silently pass to a different sample space

Comment: Generally I find it weird that we first have $P:\mathcal{\Omega} \rightarrow[0,1]$ and then suddenly use $P$ to evaluate probabilities of a different sample space $\Omega^n$...

Comment: Each individual $X_k$ **is** a function from $\Omega$ to $[0,1]$. But they’re independent functions, so in effect they’re functions on disjoint copies of $\Omega$, one for each $k$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah, I see. That was a big misunderstanding that was just cleared up. Thanks a lot!. But how about the "overloaded" use of $P$ ?

Comment: The outcomes for the whole experiment are infinite sequences of successes and failures, not individual successes and failures, so the sample space for the whole experiment is $\Omega^{\Bbb N}$. It bears a probability measure derived from that on $\Omega$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I thought about it a little bit: To define the probability measure on $\Omega^{\mathbb{N}}$ probably requires measure theory; also in the link I provided it isn't mentioned explicitly, so I wonder: Is this a general feature of undergraduate texts to tacitly assume such a derived measure exists ? Or is there some other way to derive the geometric distribution, without using that measure ?

Comment: I also have another question to your comment about the $X_k$: You said "*But* they’re independent functions"; do you mean by that, that we *suppose* that they're independent (since our intuition/reality etc. tells us so), or do you somehow *deduce* that they have to be independent (sorry about all these questions, but your answers really help!!)

Comment: It doesn't require measure theory. In discrete cases like this one, that's just a fancy word for discrete probability distribution. The derivation usually used that you quote, and Brian Scott's comments, make that amply clear.

Comment: The assumption that they’re independent is part of our mathematical model of coin tossing and part of the definition of the geometric distribution. And it’s this independence that gives the desired measure at the elementary level.

Comment: @gnometorule But I can't think of any way to define a measure $P$ on $\{(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots )\mid \omega_i\in\{f,s\}\}=\Omega^\mathbb{N}$, where on  $\Omega$ I have $\widetilde{p}(s):=p, \ \widetilde{p}(f):=1-p$, since I would get an infinite product. Could you tell me how to do it ? Or is the infinite product somehow what I want ?

Comment: You’re actually interested in the measures of subsets of $\Omega^{\Bbb N}$. These are defined in the natural way for [cylinder sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set), which is actually all that you need for the geometric distribution.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I imagine we defined $P$ on $[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n]$ as $P([\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n]):=\widetilde{p}(\omega_1)\cdot \ldots \cdot \widetilde{p}(\omega_n)$ ? And slightly offtopic (but still very relevant to me): Does it even make sense to talk of independence of random variables $X_k$, if their domains are disjoint sets (disjoint copies of $\Omega$) ? In the definition of random variables, like the one here http://www.statlect.com/inddst1.htm, I always assumed they were defined on the same domain (since their domain is never specified)...

Comment: (cont)(since otherwise *a priori* we can't talk about $P(Y=a \cap Z=b)$; I know that in this example we can, but generally we don't have a product space of the sample spaces of $Y$ and $Z$ at our disposition - or is it convention to always pass to this product sets,if the variables have disjoint domain,  so the it makes sense to ask about independence ?)

Comment: Take a look at the section *Independence between discrete random variables* on that web page: it shows you how you need to think about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve tried to summarize in this answer some of the discussion in the comments.

The root of your difficulty, I think, is confusion about the appropriate sample spaces. On the one hand you have the Bernoulli random variables $X_k$ for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$; each of them is a function on the sample space $\Omega$ taking values in $\{0,1\}$. We define $P(\{s\})=p$ and $P(\{f\})=1-p$, from which we have automatically that $$P_{X_k}(\{1\})=P(X_k=1)=P(\{s\})=p$$ and $$P_{X_k}(\{0\})=P(X_k=0)=P(\{f\})=1-p\;.$$

On the other hand you have the geometric random variable $N$, defined as the least $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $X_k=1$. The experiment in this case is to perform an infinite sequence $\mathbf X=\langle X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots\rangle$ of independent Bernoulli trials, so the possible outcomes are the infinite sequences that are the points of the Cartesian product $\Omega^{\Bbb Z^+}$.

Note that independence of the Bernoulli trials is part of the definition of a geometric random variable. Thus, even without access to any measure theory we can naïvely argue that

$$\begin{align*}
P_N(\{k\})&=P(N=k)\\
&=P(X_1=0~\&~X_2=0~\&~\ldots~\&~X_{k-1}=0~\&~X_k=1)\\
&\overset{*}=P(X_1=0)\cdot P(X_2=0)\cdot\ldots\cdot P(X_{k-1}=0)\cdot P(X_k=1)\\
&=(1-p)^{k-1}p\;,
\end{align*}$$

using independence of the $X_i$ to justify the starred equality.

However, we can also look at the set of outcomes resulting in $N=k$: it’s

$$\left\{\omega\in\Omega^{\Bbb Z^+}:N(\omega)=k\right\}=\left\{\langle\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\dots\rangle\in\Omega^{\Bbb Z^+}:\omega_1=\ldots=\omega_{k-1}=f\text{ and }\omega_k=s\right\}\;.$$

If for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we let $\Omega_n=\{s,f\}$, we can write this set as

$$\left\{\omega\in\Omega^{\Bbb Z^+}:N(\omega)=k\right\}=\{f\}^{k-1}\times\{s\}\times\prod_{n>k}\Omega_n\;,$$

a [cylinder set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set) in the product $\Omega^{\Bbb Z^+}=\prod_{n\ge 1}\Omega_n$.

Note that the probability that we naïvely assigned to this set actually is the product of the probabilities associated with the individual factors: all but finitely many of those are $1$, so in effect it’s a finite product. This assignment of probabilities to cylinder sets is in fact the starting point for constructing a probability measure on the product, and for this particular setting we need nothing more.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up another chunk of unclarity. But I'm still confused (please notice that I'm only concerned with the formal details that don't seem to work together) about $$ $$1) $X_k=1$. I've seen this notation only as $P(X_k=1)$, where it means $P(\{\omega\in \Omega \mid X_k (\omega)=1\})$. So the least $k$ such that $\{\omega\in \Omega \mid X_k (\omega)=1\}$ doesn't make much sense. Shouldn't it have been $X_k(\{s\})=1$ ?$$ $$2) How the sample space $\Omega^{\mathbb{Z}^+}$ (of **X** ? Is that a random variable ?)  works together with the sample spaces of the $X_k$'s, (...)

Comment: (...) i.e. about the sample space the underlie the starred equality, which is in essence your second comment above, which I don't understand. (You told me in a comment above to look at the section *Independence between discrete random variables* in my link, but that confused me even more.) My confusion is this: Independent random variable are define on the *same* sample space (I even looked up books to back this statement up). So all the $X_k$'s are defined on the same set $\{s,f\}$. If I apply then the definition of independence in a mechanical/formal way, (...)

Comment: (...) without thinking what that means probabilistically, I end up with the fact that already $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dependent, since
$$P({X_1=1}∩{X_2=1})=P(\{\omega \in \{s,f\} \mid X_1(\{\omega\})=1\}\cap \{\omega \in \{s,f\} \mid X_2(\{\omega\})=1\})$$ $$=P(\{s\}\cap\{s\})=P(\{s\}),$$ but $$ P({X_1=1})\cdot P({X_2=1})=P(\{s\})^2,$$ and these two are for different (we assume $0<P(\{s\})<1$. $$ $$Now you told me that  I actually would have to have
$$P({X_1=1}∩{X_2=1})=P((\{1\}×Ω)∩(Ω×\{1\})).$$
But to me that is incomprehensible since these two random variables (...)

Comment: (...) are functions $X_1,X_2:\{s,f\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so we have $\{X_1 =1\}=\{\omega \in \Omega \mid X_1(\{\omega\})=1\}$, $\{X_2 =1\}=\{\omega \in \Omega \mid X_2(\{\omega\})=1\}$, so we get what I wrote in the third equation, since only $s$ lies in their intersection. (I'm really sorry for all this asking, but you're helping immensely to put me out of my misery).

Comment: @user26698: (1) It’s common to omit the argument of a random variable and just write (for instance) $X_k=1$; see remark (1) [here](http://www.statlect.com/prbdst1.htm). And no, it’s $$P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega^{\Bbb Z^+}:\omega_k=s\right\}\right)\;.$$

Comment: But if $\{ X_k=1\}=\{\omega \in \Omega^{\mathbb{Z}^+} \mid \omega_k=s\}$, then why did you say "each of them [the $X_k$] is a function on the sample space $\Omega$ taking values in $\{0,1\}$" ? Either for every $k$ we have the functions $X_k:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or the functions $X_k:\Omega^{\mathbb{Z}^+}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. This is probably the issue my whole misunderstandings are centered about...

Comment: @user26698: Individually each $X_k$ is a function on $\Omega$. In the context of the sequence of Bernoulli trials, however, what we’re actually looking at is not $X_k$ itself, but rather the composition $X_k\circ\pi_k$, where $\pi_k(\omega)=\omega_k$ is the canonical projection map from the product to the $k$-th factor.

Comment: Ah, finally it begins to dawn on me...So if I say in the context of Bernoulli trials of, say, length $n$, that some $X_k:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are independent, I actually mean that $X_k \circ \pi_k :\Omega^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are independent, right ?

Comment: @user26698: Yes. And that should help you make sense of that *Independence between discrete random variables* link: that example with the discrete random vector is the case $n=2$.

Comment: Last question (before I try to get all my friends on math.SE to upvote this answer out of gratitude!): You said in the answer "This assignment of probabilities to cylinder sets is in fact the starting point for constructing a probability measure on the product". Did you mean by that, that although we *asssumption* of the $X_k$ being independent belonged to the definition of a geometric random variable, in the context of measure theory we can do without this assumption ?

Comment: @user26698: No, it’s still an underlying assumption. I just meant to indicate that what is generally presented informally at the undergraduate level in terms of multiplying probabilities of independent events isn’t contradicted by what is done in a more sophisticated approach; the latter actually has pretty much the same starting point. And before I forget: you’re asking the right kinds of questions.